# Heat transfer problems

Tags: thermodynamics

A tank contains 4000 lts of chromic solution at 33 degree centigrade is surrounded by a nest of brass tubes. Water at 80 degree centigrade is flowing through the tubes. How to calculate the heat transfer form hot water to the cold solution.

Comment: http://se.u.94y.info for a list of potentially helpful resources